# wrong encoding for german umlauts as command line params

Tags: c++, encoding, stl, qt-creator

I have a serious problem here with my QTCreator runnning x64 ArchLinux.
Commandline parameters containing german umlauts are invalid.
I would like to convert them into std::string, which should be possible,
at least this is all I could ever read about it.

```
std::string arg(argv[1]);
// do something with arg
```

If I look into the variable using the debugger it shows a somewhat escaped string.
For instance, ä becomes "=\". However, if I

```
std::cout << arg << std::endl;
```

the variable is totally OK on my console (urxvt).

I checked the editor setting of QtCreator (which I never touched before)
and it says, it uses UTF-8. I converted the source files into UTF-8 after
I added some umlauts into a comment and executed

```
% iconv -f ascii -t utf-8 main.cpp > _main.cpp
% mv _main.cpp main.cpp
# qtcreator recognized the change and ask me to reload the file, what I did

% file -bi main.cpp
# then results text/x-c; charset=utf-8, was text/x-c; charset=us-ascii before
```

Nothing worked. I can't even define a std::string containing an umlaut:

```
std::string s("Mäx");
// the GDB debugger show 's' as: M=\x
```

Then I defined UNICODE from within my .pro file

```
DEFINES += UNICODE
# also without success
```

To mystify it even more, the following has a different effect:

```
std::vector< std::string > list(argv, argv + argc);
# the debugger shows 2 elements (which is correct)
# but the element at index 1 looks like this: "MÃ¤x"
```

I am totally helpless. Maybe someone can help.
Thanks

@Olaf:

```
// lacks sanity checks but good enough for testing
std::wstring Encoding::char2Wide(const char *chars) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    // get the length of the string to convert
    int len = mbstowcs(NULL, chars, 0) + 1;

    wchar_t* result = new wchar_t[len];
    len = mbstowcs(result, chars, len);

    std::wstring s(result);
    return s;
}
```

**11 FEB 2013**

to clarify it a little bit, this picture shows the problem with std::string
[image: problem with std::string]

Output on the console is NOT the problem. It's completely fine. Here are my locale settings

```
% locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**HAHA:**

```
if ( s == "Mäx" ) std::cout << "Yeahhh" << endl;
-> Yeahhh (what the fxxx!)
```

Maybe this is only a qtcreator issue. I tried this simple example today with visual studio and all went as expected. And, well, it works as I expect using Eclipse CDT on Linux too. GDB shows the proper value. I Think, I will file a bug.

**UPDATE**

look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14801772/76591 for the correct answer.

Comment: Where's [Dietmar Kühl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1120273/dietmar-kuhl) when you need him. He experiences this every time he types his own f'ing *name* in as input to a console app. =P

Comment: Actually it sounds like everything is perfectly OK. The right value is printed on the console. Problem solved. What you see in the debugger are the UTF-8 bytes. That is to be expected.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Why do you think it is expected to see the UTF-8 bytes in the debugger. On my system it shows the string as `Mäx` in gdb and not as `MÃ¤x` or `M=\x`.

Comment: @Olaf Because OP is using Linux, and the default locale (`$LANG`) uses UTF-8 so that’s what C++ is getting in the command line arguments. Whereas you are probably using Windows where the default locale is Windows-1252. Either way, `std::string` and `char*` are utterly encoding agnostic. They do not support, nor care, about different encodings, they store *bytes*. /EDIT Just read that you are using Ubuntu which is quite weird, I would have thought that too used UTF-8 by default.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I do use UTF-8 everywhere, emacs, gdb, terminal, firefox, ...

Comment: @Olaf Then your GDB is either broken or (more likely) you’ve loaded a macro that interprets `char*` as strings in the current locale rather than what they actually are: encoding-agnostic byte strings. However, this is the crux of OP’s question: neither `char*` nor `std::string` have an associated encoding. I cannot stress that enough. They simply pass through the bytes they receive without any handling.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Gdb is neither broken, nor are any pretty printers loaded. My terminal is just set up properly. If I change the terminal's encoding to `iso-8859-1`, I can see `MÃ¤x` as well.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, apologies, I didn’t consider that GDB would consider byte sequences as *strings* by default (rather than byte sequences). IMO that’s just plain wrong, but I can see why it does that. What I expected GDB to do was to actually format byte sequences (i.e. escape symbols > 127) but it does exactly what you said.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Never mind, no need to apologize. I played with urxvt and was able to reproduce the behaviour, OP is seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all depends on the encoding used in the various programs, qtcreator, urxvt, gdb, ....

Converting from `ascii` to `utf-8` doesn't make sense, because every ascii only file is already utf-8 encoded. The first 127 utf-8 characters are the same as the 127 us-ascii characters.

When I look at `std::string s("Mäx");` in gdb, I see

> (gdb) p s
>   $1 = {static npos = <optimized out>,
>     _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data  fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x602028 "Mäx"}}

Your last example,

> # but the element at index 1 looks like this: "MÃ¤x"

shows the output is using `iso-8859-1`, because `ä` in utf-8 is the two byte character `303 244` octal. You can verfiy this with `man iso-8859-1` respectively.

So, if you see different output in the various programs, this means they use different encodings.

You have two programs involved, urxvt and qtcreator.

According to this message [QtCreator and UTF-8](http://lists.qt.nokia.com/public/qt-creator/2009-October/004697.html), for qtcreator, you must set the encoding in the project's settings.

For urxvt, the environment seems to be responsible. I have set `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`, which works fine for UTF-8 strings. However, if I start urxvt with

> LANG=de_DE urxvt

it shows the UTF-8 string `Mäx` as `MÃ¤x` on output, or as `"M\303\244x` in gdb.

You can test the different behaviour when you start urxvt with

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 urxvt
```

or

```
LANG=en_US urxvt
```

and compare the respective output.

**Update**:

You can change the display for plain C strings with a right click on `argv[1]`->"Change display format"->"UTF-8 string".

For `std::string` display, the `M=\x` comes from the debugging helpers. I disabled the debugging helpers under "Tools"->"Options"->"Debugger"->"Debugging helper". Then you can see the individual members of `std::string` and change `_M_p` to display UTF-8 strings as well.

Comment: hmm, I know it's about encoding but not, how to fix this ;) Strange enough: the two different versions of Mäx are shown at the same program runtime. I successfully converted char* into std::wstring - but then I had to convert this again into std::string.

Comment: @tfl How did you convert `char*` to `std::wstring` to `std::string`?

Comment: @tfl I just installed urxvt on my system (Ubuntu 12.04) and it worked out of the box, displaying `Mäx` as `Mäx`.

Comment: as I said: displaying work fine. But I need to work with the string ;)

Comment: updated code to show how I convert from char* to std::wstring

Comment: @tfl I tried your code and, ignoring the memory leak, everything looks fine.

Comment: @tfl Ok, I've always used gdb on the console. That is the reason, why I see the correct output. I installed qt creator and played with it. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: You are my hero! I would have never thought about right clickin' the dam variable. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just use wchar_t** as second argument of main.

Comment: using wchar_t or std::wstring on Linux leads to even more confusion.